# What IIS Permission Settings to Change for an Intranet

Tags: asp.net, iis

I'm trying to publish an intranet on the IIS of my local machine. I am running IIS version 7.5 on Windows 7 Enterprise. So far I am getting HTTP Error 401.2 - Unauthorized. I have Anonymous Authentication Disabled, ASP.NET Impersonation Enabled and set to Authenticated User, and Forms Authentication Disabled.

What do I need to change either in IIS or Browser? The intranet is an MVC 4 app. Many thanks for any help.

Comment: So you are in a Domain and want to have the users authenticated? Do you want them to automatically sign on or do they have to type the Password? Why do you use impersonation?

Comment: The user will log in to their PC using their windows log on credentials. No other log on will be necessary to view the site. That is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: Remove asp.net impersonation and enable anonymous authentication.

Comment: Right now I only have anonymous authentication enabled. And still having the issue.

Comment: Did you allow user="*" in your web.config?

Answer (score 0):

Make Anonymous Authentication Enabled and rest disabled.

Comment: Then I get : Error message 401.2.: Unauthorized: Logon failed due to server configuration.  Verify that you have permission to view this directory or page based on the credentials you supplied and the authentication methods enabled on the Web server.  Contact the Web server's administrator for additional assistance.

Comment: What am I then missing please?

Answer (score 0):

I needed to install Windows Authentication protocol for my IIS. I installed minimally earlier and did not have this. So now I am using this protocol keeping all other ones being disabled and it is firing on all cylindars :)